What's the title of this old film: chips with handicaps in brain to make all people equal
More than 20 years ago I saw a film (on a black-and-white tv, possibly it was black-and-white film but not necessarily) and can't get the title.
The main plot as I remember was this: in order to make all people equal, the more intelligent ones were forced to have brain implants (as the only way to make people equal was to level all to the least intelligent). The story very much concentrates on a teenage boy whose intelligence is above the average and he is in the age he should get the implant or a new implant but something goes different than the procedure says and instead of getting to be "equaled" he gets into the circle of those who really rule the world who are very intelligent and their existence is of course secret.
There is a president of this world/community/state (not sure what it was) and he is as average as possible - he spends all the time in front of a TV and doesn't understand anything of the decisions he is supposed to make. 
There is a love story too of course - the teenage boy meets a girl and in the end they decide to rebel. 
